# Making a "scrolling" map in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, dictionary, plugins

I saw this site with a map showing different parts while scrolling https://www.visitfinland.com/destinations/. I want to make something similar in wordpress ? Do I need some plugin ?

Answer (score 1):

A scan of the website revealed no 'magic' plugins or themes to make such a scrolling map. This is probably a product of a very clever (and quite expensive) design agency. So theoretically, you could make something like this in WordPress, but you certainly need knowledge of css to accomplish that.

Comment: any idea where to start or some useful tip ?

Comment: That depends on what you exactly want to accomplish. You could look into Flash, it is simple, but it is no longer supported by most browsers. HTML/CSS is a good option, but not all SVG properties can be animated with CSS. CSS has limited possibilities for animation as well. Furthermore, CSS often needs JavaScript and can not respond to new inputs. Solo JavaScript might be the way to go, it makes web animation easy, but it does not preserve SVG when embedded as an image.

In conclusion, there are lots of options, all with pros and cons. Personally, I would start with a simple project first.